# Leer XML en ISO-8859-1 y pasar a UTF-8 (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, xml, utf-8

Estoy creando una aplicación en Android Studio. Esta se conecta a una web y recibe un xml que está en `ISO-8859-1`. La aplicación usa `UTF-8`.

Me es imposible pintar las tildes, ñ, etc. 
He usado `URLDecode.decode, xmlString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8")`, y siempre me pinta mal esos caracteres, siempre aparece **`Denominaci?n, Espa?a, etc`**.

Mi pregunta es, ¿aunque esté en ISO-8859-1, recibe el xml en esa codificación, o lo transforma a UTF-8?, no sé si me explico.

Alguna idea de como solucionar esto. Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes realizarlo de esta forma, usando los métodos [new String(byte[] bytes,
      Charset charset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D%2C%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) y [getBytes(Charset charset)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29) para convertir de  `ISO-8859-1` a `UTF-8`:

```
byte[] valorISO88591;
...
...
//*Convierte ISO-8859-1 a UTF-8.
byte[] valorUtf8 = new String(valorISO88591, "ISO-8859-1").getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Comment: Hola Jorgesys. Gracias por tu ayuda. Usando byte[] valorISO88591=xmlString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");, me ha funcionado perfectamente. Muchas gracias.